# Bind9 forward to another external IP

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have set up a DNS server using bind9 and will forward any DNS request to 1.1.1.1. It working fine with the resolving of DNS requested by users. Note that my DNS resolver is residing in a VPS and not locally in my network.

The issue is that if i would want to redirect a domain 'blocksite.com' to another external IP 100.100.100.200, how can i configure it ?

It will be something like ISP censoring prohibited website and redirect it to another IP (blocked warning page) when user tries to access to the website.

Please help.. much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to add a zone for the domain, but the feature you are probably looking for is called *Response Policy Zones* (RPZ). With an RPZ, you can add a single zone that can *lie* about the domains / hostnames you would like to block.

> [Response Policy Zone (RPZ) Rewriting](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.17/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch05.html#rpz)
>
> BIND 9 includes a limited mechanism to modify DNS responses for
>   requests analogous to email anti-spam DNS blacklists. Responses can be
>   changed to deny the existence of domains (`NXDOMAIN`), deny the
>   existence of IP addresses for domains (`NODATA`), or contain other IP
>   addresses or data.
>
> Response policy zones are named in the `response-policy` option for the
>   view or among the global options if there is no `response-policy` option
>   for the view. Response policy zones are ordinary DNS zones containing
>   RRsets that can be queried normally if allowed. It is usually best to
>   restrict those queries with something like `allow-query { localhost; };`. 
>   Note that zones using `masterfile-format map` cannot be used as
>   policy zones.

```
options {
    // . . .
    response-policy { zone "rpz"; };
}

zone "rpz" {
    type master;
    file "rpz.db";
    allow-query { 127.0.0.1; };
};
```

Then you can add the domain to the `rpz.db` file with an `A` record to your warning page server:

```
$TTL 3600
@ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. ( 2 3H 1H 1W 1H )
@ IN NS localhost.
blocked.example.com. IN A 192.0.2.1
```

Comment: Thank you sir, may i know where is the 'response-policy' option found ? is it in a file ? with regard to the 'zone "rpz" {' , which file should it be save into in /etc/bind/ ? there are a number of config file 'named.conf', named.conf.local, db.local, named.conf.option etc. Is there any website i can lookup in more detail like step by step tutorial ?

Comment: All the other configuration files are just included in `named.conf`. The `options` section can be found from `named.conf.options` and it doesn't have all the possible settings by default, but you have to add what you need. `named.conf.local` is the place where you add your zone configuration, and the zone itself is a new file.

Comment: Just to be sure what u have advised is as below. Is it correct

'named.conf.options' will contain
"options {
 directory "/var/cache/bind";
        response-policy { zone "rpz"; };
};"

'named.conf.local' will contain
"zone "rpz" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/rpz.db";
}; "

create a new file 'rpz.db'
"$TTL 10
@ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. ( 2 3H 1H 1W 1H )
@ IN NS localhost.
blocked.example.com. IN A 192.0.2.1"

Comment: Looks right: as you have `directory` (The working directory of the server. Any non-absolute pathnames in the configuration file will be taken as relative to this directory), you must specify an absolute path for your zone file. But wouldn't it be simpler to just try it out? :)

Comment: yes.. i already tried it youtube.com is change to an IP address belonging to me. When doing a nslookup, [ nslookup youtube.com <mydns> ], it shows the A record as the IP i specified, however when i try to surf youtube.com on my web browser, it still did not go to my IP address. (note that I have also changed the DNS server on my router to my DNS server IP and also the IP specified on rpz.db is a static IP which when type on web browser, my web page will be displayed.) . , but also  So, is there anything i still need to modify ?

Comment: Flush your local DNS cache. :)

Comment: yes. i did.. ipconfg /flushdns and also clear my browser cache.. With the use of wireshark, I also noticed that the IP address of youtube.com is shown as the original IP from the DNS query made.

Comment: You can test your BIND server using `dig`. If it replies correctly to direct queries, it's a client side problem.

Comment: ok Thank you so much Esa, i think the problem is that I only set 1 DNS IP (my DNS) and the other is cloudflare DNS (1.1.1.1).. probably my server responded slower, that why it got the result from cloudflare DNS instead..

Comment: By the way is there any other configuration that i can set in my 'named.conf.options' to enhance my DNS query etc?

Comment: and is there anyway to modify the CNAME, AAAA, NS, MX query result also ?

Comment: You can add any other type fake records to the RPZ zone, too. The other question is too broad; the BIND 9 *Administrator Reference Manual* (ARM) is over 300 pages ([PDF for BIND 9.14.6 ARM](https://downloads.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.14.6/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.pdf))!

Comment: Thank you Esa, really appreciated your help and advice. You helped me to solve my problem.